# justifying the YEAR column digit in Python

Tags: python, datetime, digits

I have a large data set . I converted the CSV into a dataframe with panda. The column includes the year from 1965 to 2015. The sample of this column is like

```
1965.0
  66.0
  67.0
   .
   .
   .
  69.0
1970.0
  71.0
   .
   .
  79.0
1980.0
   . 
   .
   .
2000.0
   1.0
   2.0
    .
    .
    .
  15.0
```

So my question for you is how can I change all this column to a 4 digit format without the last .0

BTW when I checked my data with .info() This column is :

```
Year                51 non-null    object
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert the column to `float`, apply a custom function that adds 1900 or 2000 respectively. cast the output of that to type `int` if that is more useful to you. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': ['1970.0',
                           '71.0',
                           '79.0',
                         '1980.0',
                         '2000.0',
                            '1.0',
                            '2.0',
                           '15.0']})

def to_4digit(i):
    if i < 1900:
        if i >= 65:
            return 1900 + i
        return 2000 + i
    return i

df['y'] = df['y'].astype(float).apply(to_4digit).astype(int)
# df['y']
# 0    1970
# 1    1971
# 2    1979
# 3    1980
# 4    2000
# 5    2001
# 6    2002
# 7    2015
```

Comment: it worked perfect, though I still can not understand your function.can you please give me some additional explanation.I am still very beginner and I know this style              def func()  if condition1: return AAA   if condition2: return BBB  return CCC

Comment: @sam_sam: a nice feature of a function object in Python is that as soon as you return a value, execution of the function body is terminated. We can make use of that here to avoid having to combine conditions etc. If you hold that in mind, you're left with the logical question how to construct the statement.

Comment: So the function when (i) is larger than 65  adds a 1900 to it and terminate the process, line 3rd and 4th of the function.When (i)  is less than 65 it adds a 2000, fifth line of the function. 
But I have 4digit lines like 1965,1970,1980,1990,2000. Why the second line is   i < 1900. The last line “return year”  returns the year if it is less than 1900?!   Thank you

Comment: @sam_sam: read it from outside to inside. 1) `i < 1900` is False, the if statement is not entered, so just return `i` (it's already a 4-digit number). 2) `i < 1900` is True (it is a 2-digit number), now we have to check whether to add 1900 or 2000. 2.1)  `i >= 65` is True, so return i+1900. 2.2) `i >= 65` is False, so return i+2000. And remember, anything that comes after a `return` is not executed as soon as the `return` itself is executed :)